# get a string between two characters and output fields with comma as separator

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have the following string:

```
":: +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 -7 -6  :: 7 cycles"
```

I want to grep everything between `::`, remove `+` sign and write numbers with comma as separator, with no space or comma in the beginning or the end:

```
1,2,3,4,5,-7,-6
```

I have tried the following:

```
echo ":: +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 -7 -6  :: 7 cycles" | sed -e 's/.*::\(.*\)::.*/\1/' | sed -e 's/+//g' -e 's/ /,/g'
```

It is not there yet. The point is that although here I have 7 fields (numbers), in my work, the number of fields can vary so I cannot just print out the fields with an 
awk statement. It needs a solution that works with any number of fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do it easily by using `::` (surrounded by space and/or plus sign) as input field separator:

```
s=":: +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 -7 -6  :: 7 cycles"
awk -F '[+ ]*::[ +]*' '{gsub(/[+ ]+/, ",", $2); print $2}' <<< "$s"

1,2,3,4,5,-7,-6
```

Comment: That is interesting. Is it possible to remove the first and last comma in the same command? So to have just 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,-7,-6 ?

Comment: Why do you have double asterisks?

Comment: oh sorry, it was typo.

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`

```
$ echo ':: +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 -7 -6  :: 7 cycles' |
  perl -F:: -lane 'print join ",", $F[1] =~ /-?\d+/g'
1,2,3,4,5,-7,-6
```

- `-F::` set `::` as field separator, result is saved in `@F` array
- `$F[1]` which is second element of `@F` array will contain  `+1 +2 +3 +4 +5 -7 -6`
- `$F[1] =~ /-?\d+/g` will return all digits with optional `-` prefix
- `join ","` will add `,` between the extracted strings
- See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for detail on `-lane` options

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash: using parameter expansions (with extended globs):

```
# Turn on extglobs
shopt -s extglob

s=":: +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 -7 -6  :: 7 cycles"

# Remove leading colons (and spaces following them)
s1=${s##::*([[:space:]])}

# Remove trailing colons (and spaces leading them)
s2=${s1%%*([[:space:]])::*}

# Remove all + signs
s3=${s2//+}

# Replace all spaces by commas
s4=${s3//+([[:space:]])/,}

# Done
echo "$s4"
```

Answer (score 0):

***gawk*** solution:

```
s=":: +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 -7 -6  :: 7 cycles"
awk -v FPAT="[+-][0-9]+" '{ r=""; 
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ gsub(/^+/,"",$i); r= (r)? r","$i : $i } print r}' <<< $s
```

- `FPAT="[+-][0-9]+"` - pattern representing field value (i.e. a number with preceding `+` or `-`)
- `gsub(/^+/,"",$i)` - remove possible `+` before a number

---

***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's/::\(.*\)::.*/\1/; s/ \([+-]\)/,\1/g; s/^,+\|+//g' <<< $s
1,2,3,4,5,-7,-6
```

- `s/::\(.*\)::.*/\1/` - captures everything between `::`

---

The output (for both approaches):

```
1,2,3,4,5,-7,-6
```